# why clCreateBuffer uses host memory?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I use C++ wrapper and create buffer with following code:

```
cl_int err(0);
unsigned int size;
void *data = GetData(/*out*/ size);   

cl::Buffer buf(m_ctx,  CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 
      size, data, &err);

free(data);
```

After that working set of my application increases by `size` bytes. And since I have 32 bit application I can't allocate more then 1.5 Gb in total, but GPU has 3 Gb.

Is it possible to allocate more buffers ?

PS. `size` is less than 128 Mb.

UPdate: I use only 1 device and it is GPU. (GeForce GTX 780 GPU NVIDIA Corporation 337.88)

Comment: I have to ask: Could it be that you have multiple platforms and/or devices, and accidentally selected the **CPU** as the device to work on (instead of the **GPU**) ?

Comment: `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` may trigger some pinned behaviour. Disabling it in favor of a normal `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` might solve the problem. If it doesn't, then that is how the driver is working in the lower levels and is probably not possible to change the behavior.

Comment: @DarkZeros Usually, `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` should not cause pinning (in contrast to `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`), but you probably know the details better than me, and in doubt, the behavior is up to the OpenCL implementation. (At least, there's probably nothing in the spec that *prevents* the implementation from pinning the memory...)

Comment: @Marco13 Yes, it should not cause pinned memory. But the standard does not define exactly how pinned memory works, and nVIDIA/AMD operate differently. My guess is that, no matter what you do, the driver will allocate memory in the host side for trashing operations even if it is not pinned and that is something that unfortunately, it can't be fixed from the user-side.

Comment: @DarkZeros Maybe, to some extent: In this particular case, it should be possible to simply allocate the memory on the device, and copy it with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, managing the host side manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reasons why the problem occurs, it is probably some underlying driver behavior.

However, disabling the special flags seems to solve it for nVIDIA platform, and probably for AMD as well. So I'm writing a proper answer.

```
cl_int err(0);
unsigned int size;
void *data = GetData(/*out*/ size);   

cl::Buffer buffer = cl::Buffer buf(m_ctx,  CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 
      size, NULL, &err);
err = queue.EnqueueWriteBuffer(buffer, CL_TRUE, NULL, size, data);

free(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to your question. Maximal size of memory chunk, that can be allocated:

```
cl_ulong max_buffer_size = 0;

cl_int ret_code = clGetDeviceInfo(Device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, 
    sizeof(cl_ulong), &max_buffer_size, NULL);

if(ret_code != CL_SUCCESS){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d happened \n", ret_code);
}
```

Generally, OpenCL API doesn't allow to allocate big (over couple hundreds of Mbytes) memory objects.

Comment: I do not allocate huge memory objects, I allocate many small objects.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Do you receive any specific errors/exceptions after 1.5 Gb total?

Comment: No, I just have no more memory to alloc in my process. But, when I bypassed this limitation using `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` I got BSOD =(.

Comment: That is definetely a bug. API should return you CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES an clCreateBuffer or clCreateImage call.

Answer (score 0):

DarkZeros was right in comments. It seems to be implementation-depended, and when I use `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` instead of flag `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` it solves problem.